# Unix: When I move a file, what's the process of it?

Tags: file, unix, copy, move

I use Unix system, and when I move a file, how does Unix handle the process?

Does it copy the file first, then delete the origin file, or any other way ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Unix, belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, moving doesn't really copy for performance reasons, unless the source and the destinations are on difference filesystems.

See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/94988/is-it-better-to-always-copy-and-delete-rather-than-move)

Comment: I am a new member of stackoverflow, and my English is not good(I am a Chinese), so, I need learning the rules of sof.Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tony No problem, you'll be learning on the way ;-)